# Luxon error - "No version specified and unable to automatically determine one."

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-module-federation, luxon

I am using webpack with react and module federation and share components between. But one of the dependency packages gives warning/error such as:

```
"Compiled with problems:X

WARNING in shared module luxon -> /Users/Desktop/settings_test/react-webpack-typescript-starter/node_modules/luxon/src/luxon.js

No version specified and unable to automatically determine one. No version in description file (usually package.json). Add version to description file /Users/skenariolabs/Desktop/settings_test/react-webpack-typescript-starter/node_modules/luxon/src/package.json, or manually specify version in shared config."
```

My webpack setup looks like this:

```
shared: {
                    ...deps,
                    'luxon': {
                        singleton: true,
                        requiredVersion: deps['luxon'],
                    },

                }
```

But it still does not work. Ive tried with different versions same issue. Also tried to delete `luxon` from `node_modules` and cleared node cache but the warning is coming. Is there atleast possibility to hide this warning message?

Comment: solution: in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71197822/module-federation-react-and-apollo-3-warnings/78162319#78162319

Answer (score 1):

The topic is old, but this worked for me:

```
luxon: {
      version: '^3.2.1',
      singleton: true,
      eager: true,
    },
```

Maybe it will help someone :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71197822/module-federation-react-and-apollo-3-warnings/78162319#78162319